# Access database query string

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, database

I have a database with two tables; StudentID is the primary key on 'StudentList' table and StudentID is the foreign key on the 'JournalEntries' table.

On my website I have a search function so users can search for a student from the StudentList and the results are displayed in a datagrid. When the user selects a student from the list a journal entry box pops up. When they fill out the journal entry pop-up box and click the submit button I need the journal entry to be entered into the JournalEntries table tied to the student id that was selected from the datagrid.

```
protected void SearchGrid_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FNameLabel.Text = SearchGrid.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text;
    LNameLabel.Text = SearchGrid.SelectedRow.Cells[2].Text;

    string constr = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=D:\Sites\Network2\nrsh\App_Data\myDB.mdb";
    string cmdstr = "SELECT StudentID FROM StudentList WHERE = SearchGrid.SelectedRow.Cells[3].Text AND INSERT into JournalEntries (Topic, SubTopic, Summary, Date, Notes) values (@Topic, @SubTopic, @Summary, @Date, @Notes)";

    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
    OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand(cmdstr, con);
    con.Open();
    //The following fields are added from the journal entry form to the corresponding database fields
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Topic", ddlTopic.Text);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SubTopic", txtSubTopic.Text);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", txtDate.Text);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Summary", txtSummary.Text);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Notes", txtNotes.Text);
    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```

So that's my thought on the logic but it's probably completely wrong since I don't know much about sql. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot combine a SELECT and INSERT statement.

.......

string myValue = SearchGrid.SelectedRow.Cells[3].Text;

You don't have the value of SearchGrid.SelectedRow.Cells[3].Text in your string..you literally have "SearchGrid.SelectedRow.Cells[3].Text"...

```
string myValue = SearchGrid.SelectedRow.Cells[3].Text;
string cmdstr = "INSERT into JournalEntries (StudentID , Topic, SubTopic, Summary, Date, Notes) values (@StudentID , @Topic, @SubTopic, @Summary, @Date, @Notes)";
```

and the later

```
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StudentID", myValue);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Topic", ddlTopic.Text);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SubTopic", txtSubTopic.Text);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", txtDate.Text);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Summary", txtSummary.Text);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Notes", txtNotes.Text);
```

I'm kinda guessing.  You should give your table names and all the columns in your table and their datatypes (int, string, etc).

EDIT:  REFACTOR.

You should create a class that accepts arguments.  You should never have database code .... sitting where your GUI code is.

```
public class JournalEntriesManager
{

public static void InsertJournalEntry ( string studentID, string topic , string subTopic, DateTime DateOf  , string summary , string notes )
{
// Your code here
}

}
```

That's like "Level 1" of "separation of concerns".

But in a nutshell, your GUI level code should COLLECT the information from the controls......and pass that info to BusinessLogic ("JournalEntriesManager" in this case).
Something like that.

Comment: Also, when you're troubleshooting a SQL statement that doesn't do what you think it should, don't complicate the issue by embedding it in your C# code. Just open up SQL Server Management Studio and enter the query directly. That way you can focus on the SQL itself rather than all the C# accoutrements around it.

Comment: Just to nitpick.  It is technically a "JET database".  The program is called "Access".  I'm letting you know (not to nitpick) but to help with future google/bing searches.

Answer (score 0):

You can't quite combine multiple statements with the AND statement, that is for combining multiple conditions together.  Also, you can't just magically associate a row in one table to a row in another, instead, your JournalEntries table should have another column in it that contains the ID of the student that the entry is associated with. When you insert a new row into the JournalEntries table, you would include the student ID in that column and that is how your journal entries will be associated with a student.

Also, your queries can not include variable names like "SearchGrid.SelectedRow.Cells[3].Text", you would have to instead insert the value of that variable directly into the query text.  Remember, you are sending this query to another server (your database server) and it has no idea what your variables are in your script.

Comment: SearchGrid.SelectedRow.Cells[3].Text is the cell with the StudentID